# heroku rails assets:precompile - manifest.yml missing files and using wrong digest string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, asset-pipeline

When I deploy to heroku, asset precompile runs, and the files it creates on the file system are correct... but, the manifest.yml is not. The digest used in the filenames is different from the files created.

public/assets/manifest.yml

```
!binary "YXBwbGljYXRpb24uanM=": application-e7e24b7d7962000157e454e789b642e6.js
!binary "YXBwbGljYXRpb24uY3Nz": application-0a13ba198587580b80dfe5e3c369418f.css
```

heroku run bash

ls -l public/assets

```
application-5a82c20d2d2a3feb6239ebec41f81686.js
application-ece138f83c868002c1cf5be8e4fd8f5a.css
```

The manifest.yml is also missing a lot of other files...

Count files in assets

```
find public/assets/ -type f | wc -l
580
```

cat public/assets/manifest.yml # only 102 lines

```
!binary "YXBwbGljYXRpb24uanM=": application-e7e24b7d7962000157e454e789b642e6.js
!binary "YXBwbGljYXRpb24uY3Nz": application-0a13ba198587580b80dfe5e3c369418f.css
!binary "YnJvd3Nlci1hcHAvcGFnZS5jc3M=": browser-app/page-936cedd1fa04a45f18716aecb8350009.css
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYXJpc3RvL2ltYWdlcy9iZ19mYWxsYmFjay5wbmc=": rails_admin/aristo/images/bg_fallback-f60c36074db5f1868f9b7c68fe9043fc.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYXJpc3RvL2ltYWdlcy9pY29uX3Nwcml0ZS5wbmc=": rails_admin/aristo/images/icon_sprite-390e9585da6dca3031b09713feeb5dfe.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYXJpc3RvL2ltYWdlcy9wcm9ncmVzc19iYXIuZ2lm": rails_admin/aristo/images/progress_bar-c1c009c71b92a6c6e043a090c3fcded3.gif
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYXJpc3RvL2ltYWdlcy9zbGlkZXJfaGFuZGxlcy5wbmc=": rails_admin/aristo/images/slider_handles-c3adcbbd8a77d6389ca59350b55e46de.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYXJpc3RvL2ltYWdlcy91aS1pY29uc18yMjIyMjJfMjU2
  eDI0MC5wbmc=
: rails_admin/aristo/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240-a7500458d8e88dfca0380953f35f41e5.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYXJpc3RvL2ltYWdlcy91aS1pY29uc180NTQ1NDVfMjU2
  eDI0MC5wbmc=
: rails_admin/aristo/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240-f8ca7675fe7be8c6f45510c6835eef57.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYnVsbGV0X2JsYWNrLnBuZw==": rails_admin/bullet_black-0949e4a0fff36d0c2c6034d6e239c012.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYnVsbGV0X3doaXRlLnBuZw==": rails_admin/bullet_white-2a46b3e1adb0cc8d2d02129aadb6e270.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY2FsZW5kYXIucG5n": rails_admin/calendar-40a4120aab095e7d097e9bbea68d02d6.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY2xvY2sucG5n": rails_admin/clock-ef6307d332cfd62b7577013e12e95750.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfYmFja2dyb3Vu
  ZC5wbmc=
: rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_background-b93a8b7a2d32bc11d35c99cde0aaf80b.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfaGV4LnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_hex-a402fc45117324a0bf3ddea3b35ba3b4.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfaHNiX2IucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_hsb_b-0da3a4c95832022eb24b84b4ab147cd4.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfaHNiX2gucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_hsb_h-9412cf9de1cf41b4966594dc505b50e8.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfaHNiX3MucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_hsb_s-aa6e1bba7cd58db5535885afa21b6127.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfaW5kaWMuZ2lm": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_indic-b49c166af2009151d707a051bebb1c16.gif
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfb3ZlcmxheS5w
  bmc=
: rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_overlay-d2412ccb0d07bd3d7bf360676870173c.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfcmdiX2IucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_rgb_b-0da3a4c95832022eb24b84b4ab147cd4.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfcmdiX2cucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_rgb_g-0eb73aa03833785d4aed356b8810e1af.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfcmdiX3IucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_rgb_r-2902eee9cb1b434d5ca29a576a9371c7.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfc2VsZWN0Lmdp
  Zg==
: rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_select-5712654f282a427ed4f902d5d42faf39.gif
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY29sb3JwaWNrZXJfc3VibWl0LnBu
  Zw==
: rails_admin/colorpicker/colorpicker_submit-ef10f2ee192d1deab58f971bc942ec3f.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX2JhY2tncm91bmQucG5n": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_background-3b77cf96333884ff281d3c1ae6d83bac.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX2hleC5wbmc=": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_hex-291383fc145c6be5a40ed1fc6b0cb7a2.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX2hzYl9iLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_hsb_b-020eeceb18544d54c6d889188306afde.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX2hzYl9oLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_hsb_h-41224a949c435f04239c56ed6fd97110.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX2hzYl9zLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_hsb_s-b4c3512a0a9ebfeb55048dc9285beeaf.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX2luZGljLmdpZg==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_indic-425aa2ecf6641fe9ed82474f16e2c97a.gif
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX3JnYl9iLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_rgb_b-e25898d3d1cc55a60e0ded2fb7d06d71.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX3JnYl9nLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_rgb_g-50dad4c62772ceca083d41435c598531.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX3JnYl9yLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_rgb_r-194147ae5e17cd172f953b34e90fbb6c.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvY3VzdG9tX3N1Ym1pdC5wbmc=": rails_admin/colorpicker/custom_submit-c1ac6f2b94896cf84c0fe2802da4d04b.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvc2VsZWN0LnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/select-0ec50a07cf8970e98c738120a1b33460.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvc2VsZWN0Mi5wbmc=": rails_admin/colorpicker/select2-9ce0f913198a3bf3d84616b644c872cf.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vY29sb3JwaWNrZXIvc2xpZGVyLnBuZw==": rails_admin/colorpicker/slider-3c3fb30a0a2b1e541fa1402525fc1e48.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbG9nby5wbmc=": rails_admin/logo-684ce242ccb0e8053ff311f2615b4fd0.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbWFnbmlmaWVyLnBuZw==": rails_admin/magnifier-0ab40a5cd58d08762b7ad23692595d5e.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbXVsdGlzZWxlY3QvaWNvbl9zcHJpdGUucG5n": rails_admin/multiselect/icon_sprite-390e9585da6dca3031b09713feeb5dfe.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbXVsdGlzZWxlY3QvdWktaWNvbi1jaXJjbGUtdHJpYW5n
  bGUtbi1kYXJrLnBuZw==
: rails_admin/multiselect/ui-icon-circle-triangle-n-dark-5afa372ad5aef1fe8217224c580884b1.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbXVsdGlzZWxlY3QvdWktaWNvbi1jaXJjbGUtdHJpYW5n
  bGUtbi1saWdodC5wbmc=
: rails_admin/multiselect/ui-icon-circle-triangle-n-light-195abdf9a8b7b530e1017149d97a62c5.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbXVsdGlzZWxlY3QvdWktaWNvbi1jaXJjbGUtdHJpYW5n
  bGUtcy1kYXJrLnBuZw==
: rails_admin/multiselect/ui-icon-circle-triangle-s-dark-138d9bcbb6a90190473099d2cad90f9b.png
? !binary |-
  cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vbXVsdGlzZWxlY3QvdWktaWNvbi1jaXJjbGUtdHJpYW5n
  bGUtcy1saWdodC5wbmc=
: rails_admin/multiselect/ui-icon-circle-triangle-s-light-243212fb18301150ef97a62aded36f1d.png
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vanF1ZXJ5LmNvbG9ycGlja2VyLmpz": rails_admin/jquery.colorpicker-301e59a5e78a781dbc729e1653d7de27.js
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vcmFpbHNfYWRtaW4uanM=": rails_admin/rails_admin-e312756541433e838f87eb6797a1c93c.js
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vYmFzZS9SRUFETUUudHh0": rails_admin/base/README-82a3c5bf21d9238c336836a3893163ae.txt
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vanF1ZXJ5LmNvbG9ycGlja2VyLmNzcw==": rails_admin/jquery.colorpicker-8575324a2173bf7302df147990bf8e90.css
!binary "cmFpbHNfYWRtaW4vcmFpbHNfYWRtaW4uY3Nz": rails_admin/rails_admin-5e9413989334606990ef265b8595d055.css
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2ZsYXRfMF9hYWFhYWFfNDB4MTAwLnBuZw==": jquery-ui/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100-8db39f751dc5d237fcf7a3a16e744e73.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2ZsYXRfNzVfZmZmZmZmXzQweDEwMC5wbmc=": jquery-ui/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100-84c9db840f81df9c16591231397f5539.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2dsYXNzXzU1X2ZiZjllZV8xeDQwMC5wbmc=": jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400-e8a6dc39c9d751a48955771438d16fbf.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2dsYXNzXzY1X2ZmZmZmZl8xeDQwMC5wbmc=": jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400-e49e13d8728b56ab7c95e522f059347c.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2dsYXNzXzc1X2RhZGFkYV8xeDQwMC5wbmc=": jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400-0323eeb569bfb07afaa6bba409d00703.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2dsYXNzXzc1X2U2ZTZlNl8xeDQwMC5wbmc=": jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400-94acd31a0040b9956ee4f4247da49fdd.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2dsYXNzXzk1X2ZlZjFlY18xeDQwMC5wbmc=": jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400-29e17851b2973c1df029683e6229d0f6.png
? !binary |-
  anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWJnX2hpZ2hsaWdodC1zb2Z0Xzc1X2NjY2NjY18xeDEw
  MC5wbmc=
: jquery-ui/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100-96e0c77173b07d1fe8361fad35de13ff.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWljb25zXzIyMjIyMl8yNTZ4MjQwLnBuZw==": jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240-239f79662ddf7c61f2b8add605bf9924.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWljb25zXzJlODNmZl8yNTZ4MjQwLnBuZw==": jquery-ui/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240-b500def2c5c6d595ed6e85ce0fd56638.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWljb25zXzQ1NDU0NV8yNTZ4MjQwLnBuZw==": jquery-ui/ui-icons_454545_256x240-0ff5862ada939a272fc7c4b3d213ddc3.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWljb25zXzg4ODg4OF8yNTZ4MjQwLnBuZw==": jquery-ui/ui-icons_888888_256x240-662d02f02bf9b588f0875d935f6e08a3.png
!binary "anF1ZXJ5LXVpL3VpLWljb25zX2NkMGEwYV8yNTZ4MjQwLnBuZw==": jquery-ui/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240-1f779c3073401e7615cc4a846f65bbf4.png
!binary "Zm9udGF3ZXNvbWUtd2ViZm9udC5lb3Q=": fontawesome-webfont-526bb3ba32a8439b68bf4c40a927f54e.eot
!binary "Zm9udGF3ZXNvbWUtd2ViZm9udC5zdmc=": fontawesome-webfont-85264752821cbcec3df1b2cad5669438.svg
!binary "Zm9udGF3ZXNvbWUtd2ViZm9udC50dGY=": fontawesome-webfont-6acc98727feecaadad2d9ff4e4ce92dd.ttf
!binary "Zm9udGF3ZXNvbWUtd2ViZm9udC53b2Zm": fontawesome-webfont-e41fd64f4725e39f1de897450ff67fc6.woff
!binary "Z2x5cGhpY29ucy1oYWxmbGluZ3Mtd2hpdGUucG5n": glyphicons-halflings-white-24ebd8146111638ab87e1420cd3c1d12.png
!binary "Z2x5cGhpY29ucy1oYWxmbGluZ3MucG5n": glyphicons-halflings-244b049448622f52162abc1c3fd520ba.png
```

ls -l public/assets/

```
total 5236
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 about_us
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   6999 2013-02-18 18:14 address-bar-target-423c1729832b7020cb2b410e9f2465fb.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   6999 2013-02-18 18:14 address-bar-target.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   7071 2013-02-18 18:14 address-bar-walmart-63353f27705fdece054d921ae301fe9a.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   7071 2013-02-18 18:14 address-bar-walmart.gif
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 affiliates
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  19913 2013-02-18 18:14 apple-8fe2a44fd057da64cf137d5a94e1b47a.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  19913 2013-02-18 18:14 apple.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 173362 2013-02-18 18:14 application-5a82c20d2d2a3feb6239ebec41f81686.js
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  55602 2013-02-18 18:14 application-5a82c20d2d2a3feb6239ebec41f81686.js.gz
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 132591 2013-02-18 18:14 application.css
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  22103 2013-02-18 18:14 application.css.gz
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 132657 2013-02-18 18:14 application-ece138f83c868002c1cf5be8e4fd8f5a.css
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  22154 2013-02-18 18:14 application-ece138f83c868002c1cf5be8e4fd8f5a.css.gz
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 173362 2013-02-18 18:14 application.js
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  55602 2013-02-18 18:14 application.js.gz
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 badges
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10207 2013-02-18 18:14 beta-775c7667c462abd6488d888404a58fdc.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10207 2013-02-18 18:14 beta.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 121341 2013-02-18 18:14 bg-b99cacad4facf1307bd636f99b8d3ba7.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  79688 2013-02-18 18:14 bg-eb500d74a0c787d9bcb5834fd0f6f677.jpg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  79688 2013-02-18 18:14 bg.jpg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 121341 2013-02-18 18:14 bg.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153    937 2013-02-18 18:14 black-10-e8ab4eb9ee49c029ff05054552389a28.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153    937 2013-02-18 18:14 black-10.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153    937 2013-02-18 18:14 black-50-b7cd25e21c9ce7b05cc1815359d4d365.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153    937 2013-02-18 18:14 black-50.png
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 browser-app
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 120476 2013-02-18 18:14 browsers-ea7005cdef53c6d90be4b8b2967b60ca.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 120476 2013-02-18 18:14 browsers.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  27403 2013-02-18 18:14 chrome-0f51f333aa608ff753d1a3a4e4bda8f3.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  27403 2013-02-18 18:14 chrome.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153    946 2013-02-18 18:14 clear-4db8e18c4871111c9db1eedb53e98c09.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153    946 2013-02-18 18:14 clear.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2004 2013-02-18 18:14 coins-3a0d6c6873e37ee16f8aa055a3d90b2a.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   9311 2013-02-18 18:14 coins-icon-60a43bcc03b6c04ada23dcaff7099668.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  19544 2013-02-18 18:14 coins-icon-da100813c94ccaeee0ddc8b58936c9b8.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   9311 2013-02-18 18:14 coins-icon.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  19544 2013-02-18 18:14 coins-icon.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2004 2013-02-18 18:14 coins.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  40456 2013-02-18 18:14 fans-ssw-bag-57d8fd1b32db58888da9784ee031a3ff.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  40456 2013-02-18 18:14 fans-ssw-bag.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  66687 2013-02-18 18:14 fb_faces-ca66db5452912d028492eeeb04da31b7.jpg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  66687 2013-02-18 18:14 fb_faces.jpg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   4817 2013-02-18 18:14 fb-logo-41898ddb7b81b96f2465079b4c208606.jpeg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10492 2013-02-18 18:14 fb-logo-77ba81fb105b213856660bee4c59a1dd.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   4817 2013-02-18 18:14 fb-logo.jpeg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10492 2013-02-18 18:14 fb-logo.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  30006 2013-02-18 18:14 fb-share-ssw-54cc710a40ea5d897514fe44f68ab883.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  30006 2013-02-18 18:14 fb-share-ssw.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  33367 2013-02-18 18:14 firefox-7d06df82365214f410e431d7921ae67a.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  33367 2013-02-18 18:14 firefox.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  48748 2013-02-18 18:14 FontAwesome-f3c826ec02ee77d0281789cd5fbf7f66.otf
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  48748 2013-02-18 18:14 FontAwesome.otf
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153  68476 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont-051ad87b009ee42d2e724ebf50750e55.ttf
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153  41752 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont-3b5c7e67198f3081bb7938bf208a0d76.woff
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153  38708 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont-469447bf12dbcbfefdf0ffc3352f358b.eot
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153 130151 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont-9a6f12d612cda3368a3da39946c8fe58.svg
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153  38708 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont.eot
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153 130151 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont.svg
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153  68476 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont.ttf
-rwx------ 1 u26153 26153  41752 2013-02-18 18:14 fontawesome-webfont.woff
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  12799 2013-02-18 18:14 glyphicons-halflings-d3c343dd8a372ea21a22144752b9013c.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  12799 2013-02-18 18:14 glyphicons-halflings.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   8777 2013-02-18 18:14 glyphicons-halflings-white-de4fb1fa1dee98c6ffca03c4df5b620e.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   8777 2013-02-18 18:14 glyphicons-halflings-white.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1689 2013-02-18 18:14 gradient-grey-top-8bfa4a656717165db04003cb3046e34e.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1689 2013-02-18 18:14 gradient-grey-top.gif
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 homepage
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1369 2013-02-18 18:14 icon16-fa1f869fe6ea1359e0d55d52fea1337c.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1369 2013-02-18 18:14 icon16.png
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 icons
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1870 2013-02-18 18:14 influencer-67dde8e08832390ab39608355a2abbc9.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1870 2013-02-18 18:14 influencer.gif
drwx------ 9 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 install
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153  12288 2013-02-18 18:16 jquery-ui
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3511 2013-02-18 18:14 logo-ed55ec01e17712349c41f9d664882a13.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   6806 2013-02-18 18:14 logo-large-976d272bddd506ad889e9c110410ee4f.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   6806 2013-02-18 18:14 logo-large.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3511 2013-02-18 18:14 logo.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3003 2013-02-18 18:14 logo-white-f1e4a127637c9088f7a76953ef4c41f2.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3003 2013-02-18 18:14 logo-white.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   9468 2013-02-18 18:14 manifest-9c0f5a3e1d4ade936e4b49257f4807aa.yml
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   9468 2013-02-18 18:14 manifest.yml
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  31520 2013-02-18 18:14 msie-7f811b6c6d3dd3f487183ca0e62784c8.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  31520 2013-02-18 18:14 msie.png
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 nav
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 partner
drwx------ 4 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:15 partners
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 pitch
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 596962 2013-02-18 18:14 pitch-deck-143486f0890ca1b82283e4ef9ce44cad.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153 596962 2013-02-18 18:14 pitch-deck.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  53834 2013-02-18 18:14 platforms-85462461dbc0fcac03419b82f9c16ff1.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  53834 2013-02-18 18:14 platforms.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2660 2013-02-18 18:14 profile-d3f366d9b5876af560fd8dbacec9ac68.jpg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2660 2013-02-18 18:14 profile.jpg
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2963 2013-02-18 18:14 quest-bar-c09f6870e4be8a6ca85628f115a7cf46.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2963 2013-02-18 18:14 quest-bar.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   6646 2013-02-18 18:14 rails-418c3aa85fbd730c557bda0bc8eebcbe.png
drwx------ 6 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 rails_admin
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   6646 2013-02-18 18:14 rails.png
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 retailers
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2724 2013-02-18 18:14 retailers-header-e872a401233c559f4c011f8178a80d0d.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2724 2013-02-18 18:14 retailers-header.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  57387 2013-02-18 18:14 reward_greeting-72cf85d68c0f929872d95b24ead99eab.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  57387 2013-02-18 18:14 reward_greeting.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2284 2013-02-18 18:14 rewards-center-ad9b8a594f8c0ee394b898bc65f11a4f.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2284 2013-02-18 18:14 rewards-center.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  29219 2013-02-18 18:14 safari-5c69387392e8d9d6a99490fd7ab60665.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  29219 2013-02-18 18:14 safari.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3498 2013-02-18 18:14 search-bar-0847c720a2e5b7b5c2727b202f592a16.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3498 2013-02-18 18:14 search-bar.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  11505 2013-02-18 18:14 search-result-amazon-cae4830bff2400c4962fc3e326ad0167.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  11505 2013-02-18 18:14 search-result-amazon.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10556 2013-02-18 18:14 search-results-amazon-shoes-f256958c297b83b581ae89205c820f62.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10556 2013-02-18 18:14 search-results-amazon-shoes.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  31729 2013-02-18 18:14 search-results-shoes-73d49e564dae6f92a99935971bbf356f.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  31729 2013-02-18 18:14 search-results-shoes.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10030 2013-02-18 18:14 search-result-target-10f95dfae95e21e38998bf7b8c82a1ff.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  10030 2013-02-18 18:14 search-result-target.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  11292 2013-02-18 18:14 search-result-walmart-5423fc95a10d54e0a602316407cdd14d.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  11292 2013-02-18 18:14 search-result-walmart.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  11306 2013-02-18 18:14 share-variables-8a93ce145d1398b2f4f36be3571d2f23.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  11306 2013-02-18 18:14 share-variables.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  21291 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-give-2f4861f75272d22fb7fd6322bfcc824a.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  33916 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-give-big-7c575fbfca0a3bdfb15d6c68a542ce00.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  33916 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-give-big.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  21291 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-give.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  22214 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-win-4bf610157aecf584f4daed02be7ec815.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  36294 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-win-big-93e7901d78b5750dc051851000dad87c.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  36294 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-win-big.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  22214 2013-02-18 18:14 shop-share-win.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  22417 2013-02-18 18:14 splash-bag-90796e21f5151e9a206ee1ceb028c913.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  22417 2013-02-18 18:14 splash-bag.gif
drwx------ 2 u26153 26153   4096 2013-02-18 18:16 spw
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  14998 2013-02-18 18:14 ssg-1234-fdddbf803e7bebea45decd659fa33a0d.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  14998 2013-02-18 18:14 ssg-1234.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2730 2013-02-18 18:14 stand-out-cea8cef3fbf56633ee97ff0c88ad8db5.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2730 2013-02-18 18:14 stand-out.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2157 2013-02-18 18:14 star-44ec12f4f4823bf54b648388e7977a93.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2157 2013-02-18 18:14 star.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3046 2013-02-18 18:14 stars-1of3-e6265146e4f9ff3d5490248eb1cd9213.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3046 2013-02-18 18:14 stars-1of3.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3044 2013-02-18 18:14 stars-2of3-4e82d03ddbfbb0ab2a8ef982f794bc26.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   3044 2013-02-18 18:14 stars-2of3.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2124 2013-02-18 18:14 stars-3of3-1f6931b75d2ebf820853b09b748a6d86.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2124 2013-02-18 18:14 stars-3of3.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2172 2013-02-18 18:14 tag-158b44efbee4c3d2114db27b000b1432.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   2172 2013-02-18 18:14 tag.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   7071 2013-02-18 18:14 Untitled-2-fd5a34230f32cf5a761b3cf208f99cae.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   7071 2013-02-18 18:14 Untitled-2.gif
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  33496 2013-02-18 18:14 windows-ec398a2f73541cc4c26d8b9f26dec6c0.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153  33496 2013-02-18 18:14 windows.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1185 2013-02-18 18:14 yellow-flag-f27b4be47c8bf15efc5a8939fabdd92a.png
-rw------- 1 u26153 26153   1185 2013-02-18 18:14 yellow-flag.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It's conceivable that `public/assets` contains old files that you have not cleaned out. If heroku are precompiling your assets on their servers, then you do not need to do so on your localhost.

Run `rake assets:clean` to get rid of the old files and forget that the `rake assets:precompile` task exists.

I'd imagine you will see a change in the situation after doing this.